# If cell A1 is greater/lesser than XX, then calculate

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm attempting to write a formula to calculate the number of positions gained/lost on a cell.

For example:
If `A1` has a positive value (example 52.13), then subtract `C1` from `B1`.
If `A1` has a negative value (example -36.12), then subtract `D1` from `B1`.

This is the formula I have been playing with:

`=IF(AND(S9>=0,N9-L9)*OR(S9<=0,M9-L9)`

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 2):

Use the below:

```
=IF(A1>0,B1-C1,B1-D1)
```

You have not said what you would want in the event of a 0 in A1, to include that you can modify and use the below:

```
=IF(A1=0,"IF ITS ZERO DO THIS",IF(A1>0,B1-C1,B1-D1))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work for you:

```
=IF(VALUE(A1)>0;B1-C1;B1-D1)
```

You have to consider yourself if the `$` like in the picture are needed or not since I made this code based on an example that I made myself.

[image]